# What is the correct usage of the inline key-val parser?

Tags: expl3, key-value

I assumed `\keyval_parse:nnn` absorbed its third argument, yet it is inserted in the input stream, why?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\noindent%
\keyval_parse:nnn{}{}{j=u}\\
\keyval_parse:nnn{\use_none:n{##1}}{\use_none:nn{##1}{##2}}{k=v}\\
\keyval_parse:NNn\use_none:n\use_none:nn{l=w}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. It's a expandable parser for key value lists which returns it's result by passing the parsed key-value pairs to user defined macros. It wouldn't be very useful if it would just remove the parsed arguments without returning them.

Comment: well if the code doesn't do anything with the argument they stay. Why should they disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the example in the documentation carefully to understand what it's doing.  Suppose a simple example of a `\keyval_parse:nn` that requires that every key has a value, just for the sake of simplification.  The input:

```latex
\keyval_parse:nn { <keyval code> } { key 1 = value 1, key 2 = value 2 }
```

is equivalent to:

```
<keyval code>{key 1}{value 1}
<keyval code>{key 2}{value 2}
```

That is, for every `key=value` it inserts `<keyval code>` followed by the `key` and the `value` in braces.  The same goes for the key-only version, but it inserts only one brace group after the code:

```
<keyval code>{key 1}
<keyval code>{key 2}
```

---

Your first two examples just print the keyval list because they are not actually using the keyval pairs.  Watch closely, same rules as before:

```latex
\keyval_parse:nnn{}{}{j=u}
```

here `<keyval code>` is empty, so it becomes:

```
%↓ empty
  {j}{u}
```

which just writes `ju` to the output.

And your second example:

```
\keyval_parse:nnn{\use_none:n{##1}}{\use_none:nn{##1}{##2}}{k=v}
```

becomes:

```
\use_none:nn{##1}{##2}{k}{v}
```

then `\use_none:nn` consumes `##1` and `##2` and again `kv` is typeset.

---

Here's a maybe more instructive example.  See what `\erwann_wrap_one:n` do to their arguments and compare to the PDF output:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\noindent
\cs_new:Npn \erwann_wrap_one:n #1 { (#1) }
\cs_new:Npn \erwann_wrap_two:nn #1 #2 { [#1--#2] }
\keyval_parse:nnn
  { \typeout{A~KEY} \erwann_wrap_one:n }
  { \typeout{A~KEY~WITH~VALUE} \erwann_wrap_two:nn }
  {
    k1,
    k2 = v,
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

This prints

```
A KEY
A KEY WITH VALUE
```

to the terminal, and the PDF will have:

> [image]

Comment: It seems odd that one would have to rely on functions to do inline stuff.

Comment: @Erwann But it's not called `\keyval_parse_inline:nnn`, that's why its arguments aren't a `<inline code>`, but just `<code>` (and it is not `_inline:` because if it were it would not be expandable).  And all `_inline` functions do is just define a temporary function with the code you provided, so you get more or less the same by defining the function by hand

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `\keyval_parse:nnn` should end with something that expects a braced argument.

The second argument, similarly, should end with something that expects two braced arguments.

In your first call, you just get `{j}{u}`.

The examples use a two-argument function and a three-argument one, but just one argument is supplied, the others will be supplied by the parsing.

Of course this is not thought for printing something, but to do some settings.

Example with printing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \erwann_test:n { \#1~is~#1 }
\cs_new:Nn \erwann_test:nn { \#1~is~#1;~ \#2~is~#2 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keyval_parse:nnn { \erwann_test:n } { \erwann_test:nn } { j=u , k }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Example with settings.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_erwann_test_seq
\prop_new:N \l_erwann_test_prop

\cs_new_protected:Nn \erwann_set:n
 {
  \keyval_parse:nnn
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_erwann_test_seq
   }
   {
    \prop_put:Nnn \l_erwann_test_prop
   }
   { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\erwann_set:n { j, k=a, yy=b, c }

\seq_show:N \l_erwann_test_seq
\prop_show:N \l_erwann_test_prop

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Result on the terminal

```
The sequence \l_erwann_test_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {j}
>  {c}.
<recently read> }

l.28 \seq_show:N \l_erwann_test_seq

?
The property list \l_erwann_test_prop contains the pairs (without outer
braces):
>  {k}  =>  {a}
>  {yy}  =>  {b}.
<recently read> }

l.29 \prop_show:N \l_erwann_test_prop

?
```

The `\keyval_parse:NNn` function will do essentially the same, but you have to pass just a one-argument and a two-argument functions. So the code above can also be written as

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_erwann_test_seq
\prop_new:N \l_erwann_test_prop

\cs_new_protected:Nn \erwann_set:n
 {
  \keyval_parse:nnn \erwann_set_one:n \erwann_set_two:nn { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \erwann_set_one:n
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_erwann_test_seq { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \erwann_set_two:nn
 {
  \prop_put:Nnn \l_erwann_test_prop { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\erwann_set:n { j, k=a, yy=b, c }

\seq_show:N \l_erwann_test_seq
\prop_show:N \l_erwann_test_prop

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```